# Azure Machine Learning Prediction - Input and Outputs

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am attempting to follow this [tutorial](http://www.toptal.com/machine-learning/predicting-gas-prices-using-azure-machine-learning-studio) however I was attempting to predict MPG for a set of cars rather than oil prices and have the following set up:

1. MPG Sample dataset
2. Remove missing values, project everything (weight, displacement, cylinders, etc) except model name
3. Split 75 to train model, 25 to score model
4. Train model on MPG column with neural network
5. Score model which is fed by Train Model and Split
6. Score model is fed to Evaluate model

This all seems to run fine and without issue, so I create a scoring experiment and then publish it as a web service, however when I attempt to input values it is asking for an MPG input. My understanding is that this would be the predicted value, so it seems somewhat opposite to have to enter this as a value, or am I just understanding a basic tenet of machine learning?

In short: Ideally I would like to be able to enter everything but the MPG and get a prediction on what the MPG is for a given set of value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also add project columns to exclude label as part of scoring experiment and connect web service output port to the output of project columns

Comment: I did do this to get a better output, how about my input?

Comment: Same for input - in scoring experiment, drop the label before sending it to scoring. If you drop label as part of input, then don't need to do it again for output

Comment: But if I drop the label I am trying to predict it gives me an error about that column not being present?

Comment: @Pseudonym I am having the same problem. How did you figure it out?

Comment: Honestly I don't fully remember as its been a while since I've looked at it, if I am remembering correctly I *think* I just took whatever output it gave me at the end and then only displayed the result I wanted to see? I'll look in a couple of hours see if I can dredge up anything

Comment: @serhatozgel sorry I couldn't find anything all my old projects are gone, what exactly do you still need help with?

Comment: @serhatozgel  care to provide a write up for future answer seekers?

Comment: Left input of the score model is connected to trained model. Right input of the score model is connected a "Project Columns", which excludes predicted column from "Train Model". After running this setup, I connected "web service input" to the right input of "Score Model" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the input format of your Rest service as the format for your training set. This is not uncommon in machine learning. In the case of a binary label, you could file this with in with a "guess" label, say 1.

Basically just fill in any value you here for your data to be scored.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying, so what your saying is that I would input my mpg "guess" and the result would be how strong the model thinks my guess is?